# Music that sounds like this [acoustic guitars and female vocals]?

Tags: similar-artists

Surfing the internet I've casually discovered this band. Any suggestions of similar artists (with this kind of vocals etc)?
Thank you !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN6mesBvObA

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the song "Coil" by Opeth. Duet with a male and female vocalist.

Answer (score 0):

LeAnn Rimes has some great music. Her vocal are very soothing and pleasing to listen to.